# Javascript add textfield button doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made the following code

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="myemailform" name="myemailform" action="form-to-email.php">
    <div id="form_container">
        <label class="description" for="pax">Number:</label>
        <div>
            <select class="select small" id="pax" name="pax">
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="31">31</option>
                <option value="32">32</option>
                <option value="33">33</option>
                <option value="34">34</option>
                <option value="35">35</option>
                <option value="36">36</option>
                <option value="37">37</option>
                <option value="38">38</option>
                <option value="39">39</option>
                <option value="40">40</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <label class="description">ID:</label>
        <input type='text' id="idpl" class="id-text-len" name='ids1' placeholder="ID #1">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type='button' id='btnMore' value='Add Ids'>
</form>
```

js:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('#btnMore').click(function () {
        var form, fields, newField;

        var e = document.getElementById("pax");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

        form = $("#myemailform");
        for (var i = 1; i < strUser; i++) {
            fields = form.find("input[name^='ids']");
            newField = $(fields[0]).clone();
            newField.attr('name', 'ids' + (fields.length + 1));
            newField.attr('placeholder', 'ID #' + (fields.length + 1));
            newField.insertAfter(fields.last());
        }
    });

});
```

You can see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7QUea/1/) .

What i want is when i click on the button to add fields, not add more on the existing but new.

I mean e.g. first time i click 10 and then add, as a results i'll get 10 textfields. Then if i click 14 i don't want to get 10+14=24 textfields but 4 more, i want 14textfields.

I haven't made it up to do that. Please someone help me by code, in general i know why that's happening but i don't know how to solve that.

Comment: Just FYI, there is an additional bug you've not spotted - you're only adding (selection - 1) records, due to your `for` loop conditions.

Comment: try remove() the oldest input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var form = $("#myemailform");;

    $('#btnMore').click(function() {
        var fields, newField;

        var opt = parseInt($('#pax').val());
        var len = opt - $('.id-text-len').length;

        if(len> 0){
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                fields = form.find(".id-text-len");
                newField = $(fields[0]).clone();
                newField.attr('name', 'ids' + (fields.length + 1));
                newField.attr('placeholder', 'ID #' + (fields.length + 1));
                newField.val('');
                newField.insertAfter(fields.last());
            }
        } else {
            form.find(".id-text-len:gt("+ (opt - 1) +")").remove()
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3jMJF/)

Comment: Seems to work when you're going up, i mean from 10 to 13 adds 3 but what if you go from 10 to 7? Nothing happens, i think that must be considered also.

Comment: @Mhche in the accepted answer if you had entered any data in the text fields it is lost, case select 6 enter values 1,2,3 etc then change the selection to 3 all data get resetted here

Comment: Yes you are right i haven't noticed by overexcitement but in your solution also if you have 3 textfields values 1,2,3 and then select 6 then the 3 rest takes the first textfields value.

Comment: @Mhche try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3jMJF/3/ - another point is I'm not using the id property here, it is removed. If you want you need to set it along with the name attribute

Comment: yes because i don't want either to use the id property. And i suppose that's exactly the wright answer now. Please edit you answer you to make it accepted.

Comment: Good, i didn't noticed that value should be remain if readding

Comment: @Arun P Johny Could you please help me a little bit more on that? So not to make new question.
http://jsfiddle.net/3jMJF/5/  I want them each time to be shown in a new line like they are now (vorname,name,xxx/xx/xxxx) and messed up as they do now.

Comment: Thank you very much but i have the following problem. http://jsfiddle.net/Kk7TD/2/
As you see if there is other elements below they are created bellow all elements and not bellow their selfs.

Answer (score 1):

how about this

http://jsfiddle.net/7QUea/3/

i think this is the one you need

just one more line

```
$("input[name^='ids']").not("input[name='ids1']").remove();


jQuery(function($) {

   $('#btnMore').click(function() {
      $("input[name^='ids']").not("input[name='ids1']").remove();
         var form, fields, newField;
         var e = document.getElementById("pax");
         var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

         form = $("#myemailform");
         for (var i = 1; i < strUser; i++) {
         fields = form.find("input[name^='ids']");
         newField = $(fields[0]).clone();
         newField.attr('name', 'ids' + (fields.length + 1));
         newField.attr('placeholder', 'ID #' + (fields.length + 1));
         newField.insertAfter(fields.last());}
                            });
   });
```

Comment: I'm wondering, if you know how to use clone(), why you didn't know you can try remove()

Comment: I have tried with another button with the remove() but the problem was that was taking the lastChild that meant the #1 input two and after two clicks on it doesn't worked at all.

Answer (score 0):

Changed a few things (now it is more jQuery styled):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#btnMore').click(function () {
        var strUser = $("#pax").val();       
        var form = $("#myemailform");        
        var fields = form.find("input[name^='ids']");    
        for (var i = 0; i < (strUser - fields.length); i++) {
            var newField = $(fields[0]).clone();
            newField.attr('name', 'ids' + (fields.length + 1 + i));
            newField.attr('placeholder', 'ID #' + (fields.length + 1 + i));        
            form.find("input[name^='ids']").last().after(newField);
        }
    });
});
```

Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/7QUea/4/

Comment: From the description it wasn't clear that it is a "set" button and not an "add" button... well you have a working solution, so everything is great

Comment: Maybe my false, i am sorry for that and thanks for the response :)